# sweetAlert not working properly inside a jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, web, sweetalert

I am trying to integrate sweetalert in my JSP project, the problem is when I am replacing a normal java script alert with sweetalert as below

```
{

    %>

       <script>
           sweetAlert("hello");
           window.location.href="reg.jsp";      
       </script>  
    <%

}
```

alert box is flashing for a second and reg page is loading off , dont no how to fix it , can some one help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.location.href should be called at button click handler;

```
<script>
    swal({
            text: "hello",
        },
        function () {
            window.location.href = "reg.jsp";
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man you saved my life ! i have been struggling with this from couple of days ! cheers

Answer (score 0):

when you use window.location.href you are also closing also the sweetalert you just called before, do it the other way.
first set the location you desire then use the alert!